# API working fine in postman but not in angular2

Tags: angular

I have an API to send an OTP to mobile. It is working fine via PostMan but not via angular2.

I am getting this error "Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response."

Any help

Thanks in advance 
[image]

Comment: The browser checks if the headers are present and throws an error if not. Postman works around the browser and doesn't check for these headers. Either you reconfigure the server to provide the expected headers, or you use your own server that forwards requests to the other server, so that the browser doesn't recognize the CORS situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a backend issue, backend developer has to write code to allow headers and allow origin for all APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Include `Allow-Cross-Origin` header in your `POST` call.